# Error with Typescript / whatwg-fetch / webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, fetch

I'm trying to have a simple demo app working using Typescript and React, with webpack. When I try to add whatgw-fetch to retrieve data from a server, I get this error when running webpack :

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'whatwg-fetch'
```

The error is on the import line :

```
import * as Fetch from 'whatwg-fetch'
```

I did install the npm dependency and the typing for typescript

```
npm install --save whatwg-fetch
typings install --global --save dt~whatwg-fetch
```

My webpack configuration is :

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/index.tsx')
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension. 
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.tsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "ts-loader"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

I don't see any error in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and if I change the import to some module that actually is not there, I get a different error (`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'whatwg-fetcha' in C:\dev\[...]`), and my IDE tells me the import is not valid.

The import for basic React works fine with an equivalent setting :

```
npm install --save react
typings install --global --save dt~react
import * as React from 'react'
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some more research (and actually writing the question down), it seems that the typing for whatwg-fetch is in this use case : [Import a module for side-effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only) (as described on the site : Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports.)

So instead of

```
import * as Fetch from 'whatwg-fetch'
```

I used

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

And I don't get any more errors and I can use the fetch function in my component. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: hi, I tried the same but it tells me fetch is not defined at runtime. any solution?

Comment: you need to use the github shim to polyfill it for browsers that don't support it yet : https://github.com/github/fetch @SalmanHasratKhan

Comment: Just in care you're using typescript and getting "Promise is not defined" errors, make sure your target in tsconfig file is "es6" or above.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for dynamic imports, `import('whatwg-fetch')`

Answer (score -1):

Aside from @Antoine solution, I also needed to add `@types/whatwg-fetch` to my project to make it work:

```
npm install --save @types/whatwg-fetch
```